# Ignoring "=" character with fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read a file that contains lines in this format `abc=1234`. How can I make fscanf ignore the `=` and store `str1="abc"` and `str2="1234"`?

I tried this:

```
fscanf(fich1, "%[^=]=%[^=]" , palavra, num_char)
```

Comment: how are `palavra` and `num_char` declared?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `fgets` to read lines and then parse them with `sscanf`. But you can use the same principle for just `fscanf` if you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[100];
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];

    if(! fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) return 1;

    if(sscanf(buf, "%[^=]=%s", str1, str2) != 2) return 1;

    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);
}
```

So what does `%[^=]=%s` do? First `%[^=]` reads everything until the first occurrence of `=` and stores it in `str1`. Then it reads a `=` and discards it. Then it reads a string to `str2`. And here you can see the problem with your format string. `%[^=]` expects the string to end with `=`, and you have another one at the end. So you would have a successful read of the string `abc=1234=`.

Note that `%[^=]` and `%s` treats white space a little differently. So if that's a concern, you need to account for that. For example with `%[^=]=%[^\n]`.

And in order to avoid buffer overflow, you also might want to do `%99[^=]=%99[^\n]`.